# Yarn 2 PnP, VSCode and @types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, yarnpkg

I'd like to get intellisense working for a remote library (Chart.js) without including it as a dependency (it is loaded via CDN).

So I am using `@types/chart.js` to allow intellisence.

1. `yarn add -D @types/chart.js`
2. add `/// <reference types="chart.js" />` to my js script

It works fine with Yarn classic and npm but I cannot get it to work with Yarn 2 Pnp. Whenever I try, I get error `Cannot find type definition file for 'chart.js'.ts(2688)` and intellisence (obviously) stops working.

Is there any way to include `@types` while using Yarn 2 Pnp without using a loader?

Answer (score -2):

**Add this into your `.yarnrc.yml` file**

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
```